# How to kill a not running process in Android

Tags: android, process, kill

Does anybody meet this situation before? I force stop an app in the setting dialog in a Android device.
But when I use `ps` command via `adb` it is still displayed on the screen. But this process can't be get by the `activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses()`. This process even exists after I uninstall this app, It happened randomly.

Because I opened a port in my app using `ServerSocket`, the port can't be released after I stop my app.
The next time I tried to open my app, it failed to using this port again.

I am using a ASUS EeePad and this problem seems only happened on that device.

By the way, the process can't be get by any 3rd party tools such as process manager.
But it really exists with a `pid` when I use `ps` via `adb shell` to list all processes.

Comment: can you share (copy/paste) the ps -aux output? It could be a user issue or something to do with the Linux / Android integration.

Comment: Can you share more information? Did you release the port (closed the socket) inside the onDestroy() method override?

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no code .. here are some hints :

1-do you close your connection ??? that will be the main reason to hold the port busy.

2- deal with socket more safely when your app going to pause , stop, or being destroyed .. you can override onpause,onstop, or ondesotry ..and free the port before closing the app.

3- make connection in a separated thread and implement a timer  to check if you really need the port or not ( I mean if your app is alive or not ) and based on that kill/leave the thread (connection)

4- in worst cases .. if you have control over the other side of connection ( server, device .. ) try to make your solution more flexible like making range of ports to firstly check then use if they are  available.

good luck